# Kubernetes install on vSphere failing

Tags: kubernetes

Just trying to install a test instance of Kubernetes on my vSphere cluster.  I'm following the install instructions on kubernetes.io and get to the point where I run:

```
govc import.vmdk kube.vmdk ./kube/
```

The vmdk gets uploaded and imported, but the following happens on my cluster:

```
Create virtual machine  [Cluster]  -- Completes
Clone virtual machine   kube-srcvm -- Completes
Reconfigure vm          kube-srcvm -- Completes
Delete virtual machine  kube-srcvm -- Completes
Reconfigure vm          kube-dstvm -- Completes
Delete virtual machine  kube-dstvm -- Completes
Delete virtual disk                -- Completes
```

From there I try ./kube-up.sh:

```
... Starting cluster using provider: vsphere
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
Starting master VM (This can take a minute)...
Error: A specified parameter was not correct.
```

I'm relatively sure my config is ok:

```
export GOVC_URL='https://user:pass@mydomain/sdk'
export GOVC_DATACENTER='My Datacenter'
export GOVC_DATASTORE='datastore3'
export GOVC_RESOURCE_POOL='/My Datacenter/host/My Cluster/Resources/Kubernetes/'
export GOVC_NETWORK='VM Network'
export GOVC_GUEST_LOGIN='kube:kube'
```

So yeah, not really sure where to go from here -- any insight would be greatly appreciated.  I should add that I'm trying this on a vsphere 5.1 cluster.

Comment: The vsphere support for Kubernetes is not very actively maintained.  You could try filing an issue on github and mentioning @pietern who wrote that code.

You could also try this other vmware guide: https://github.com/xavierbaude/VMware-coreos-multi-nodes-Kubernetes

I can tell you that error message, `Error: A specified parameter was not correct`, is not coming from any Kubernetes code.  Probably this is coming from the `govc` command when it is run from function `kube-up-vm` in `kubernetes/cluster/vsphere/util.sh`.   Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Vsphere support is broken and not actively supported.